# Is there a shortcut or hotkey that I could use to access the Transform panel of the properties shelf in the 3D viewport?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

While working on vertices, and wanting a bit more precision than I can get with a mouse, I use the transform panel of the properties shelf in the 3D viewport. But to do this, I have to move the mouse over to the panel, make my adjustments with the keyboard, and then mouse back over to the vertices I'm working with. Is there a shortcut or hotkey that could eliminate the mouse moves?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the keyboard shortcuts combined with the **Arrow Keys**.

For example: in top view pressing <kbd>**G**</kbd> and the up/down arrow keys will move the selected vertices on the vertical (**Y**) axis. The left and right arrows will move on the horixontal (**X**) axis.

On any side view, the up/down arrows will control movement on the **Z** axis.

You can still use constraints like <kbd>**G**</kbd><kbd>**X**</kbd>, <kbd>**G**</kbd> <kbd>**Y**</kbd>, <kbd>**G**</kbd><kbd>**Z**</kbd> to limit the movement to one axis

The precision of your movements will depend on how far you zoom in on the viewport.

For even smaller moves you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can type the amount you want to transform the vertices when using <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd>.

E.g. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>-3</kbd> will translate the selection `-3` blender units on the X axis.

Comment: I agree. But what I usually want is to move a vertex that has a dimension on the z axis of 31.873 to 30.742. It's quicker to use the z parameter in the transform panel to enter 30.742 than it is to calculate the difference (-1.131), and then use the key combination "GX-1.131". Achieves the same result, but not as fast or efficient as if there was a hotkey or hotkey combination, for example, "Z that would directly access that parameter.

Comment: You can type in an expression if you press `=`, e.g. `G X = 31.873-30.742`

Comment: True, and that's a capability I use frequently in Blender (and in GIMP, too, which supports regular expressions), but not so much when using g, s, and r. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Or to improve on the idea, "GZ might be a good hotkey combination for directly accessing the Z dimension in the translation panel in edit or object mode; "SY might similarly be a good combination to directly access the X dimension in the Scale panel in object mode, and "RX might be a good combination to access the amount to rotate the value around the x axis.